# Powershell: Why does Rename-Item not work as a piped command?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, pipeline

In this script, everything is working as I expect for the most part. However, the rename operation will only work outside of these piped commands

```
 Get-ChildItem -Path $folderpath -Filter $folderfile | Move-Item - 
Destination $destination | sleep 5  | Out-File -FilePath $logpath -Append
```

If I try to do the rename as part of the piped commands, it simply doesn't work. Anywhere outside of that and it will work for a single iteratrion of the filewatcher, and then no more. Why will the rename not work as a piped command?

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $folderpath -Filter $folderfile | Move-Item -Destination $destination | Rename-Item $destination$folderfile -NewName $newname  | Out-File -FilePath $logpath -Append
```

Comment: Can you reduce the code to only the relevant portion please?

Comment: Sure. No problem. Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Move-Item` does not output to the pipeline by default. Use the **-PassThru** switch:

> -PassThru
>     Returns an object representing the item with which you are working. By default, this cmdlet does not generate any output.

That will pipe it directly into `Rename-Item` and you have to specify `-NewName` only:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $folderpath -Filter $folderfile | 
Move-Item -Destination $destination -PassThru |
Rename-Item -NewName $newname -PassThru |
Out-File -FilePath $logpath -Append
```

Also, you don't even have to use `Rename-Item` at all but move it directly to the final target directory + name (assuming `$destination` is a directory path):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $folderpath -Filter $folderfile | 
Move-Item -Destination (Join-Path $destination $newname) -PassThru |
Out-File -FilePath $logpath -Append
```